# iOS UIWebview error Plug-in handled load: not able to play video from s3 bucket url which is upload from android device

Tags: ios, swift, webview

We are uploading and playing captured videos from both android and iOS devices. we are uploading in to s3 bucket.I am successfully playing video which is uploaded from iOS devices, I am getting the error `Plug-in handled load` for video uploaded from android device. I am using `UIWebView` to playing the videos. if I am using `WKWebView` also getting same issue

my code is here

```
self.webView = UIWebView(frame: self.previewView.bounds)
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
self.webView.delegate = self
self.webView.isOpaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
self.previewView.addSubview(webView)
let userAgent = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")!+ "Custom agent"
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : userAgent])
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I am getting below error

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=204 "Plug-in handled load" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx-xxx-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/my_web_videos/video/xxx/video.mp4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx-xxx-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/my_web_videos/video/xxx/video.mp4, WebKitErrorMIMETypeKey=video/mp4, NSLocalizedDescription=Plug-in handled load}
```

I have tried solutions one of [stackoverflow post for user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview/1368399#1368399) it suddenly stopped working. Can anyone help me how to solve this issue. **Thank You in Advance**

Comment: UIWebView is now deprecated replace UIWebView to WKWebView

Comment: same issue with WKWebView also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an audio compatibility issue from android video capturing. based on 
**[Video compatibility issue: android recorded video not played in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16437021/4263824)** stack overflow answer my android team changed audio format **AMR** to **AAC**. Now we are able to play video captured from android device in iOS Devices.